# How access to 2 Web services with 1 Session? Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have 2 Web Services from same web site, I have to access both with 1 Session

Example:

```
Create Soap Client       ${CURDIR}\\SecurityServiceService.wsdl
Set Proxies     http     ${PROXY}
 ${result}=       Call Soap Method  authenticateUserInternalSecurity      ${USERNAME}   ${PASSWORD}    1   #SecurityServiceService


Create Soap Client       ${CURDIR}\\DelinquentServiceService.wsdl
Set Proxies     http     ${PROXY}
${result}=       Call Soap Method        getMultipleLovBei010                                                   #DelinquentServiceService
     log    ${result}
    delete all sessions
```

With the Security service access to Delinquent Services.

My error:

> WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Operation: getMultipleLovBei010 called
>   without a  valid session.'

Thanks,

Regards

Comment: please fix the formatting of your code to make it more readable.

Comment: perhaps you should check with your dev team to learn how they handle the session. Perhaps you can set a header in the second client based on data from the result of the authentication call.

Answer (score 0):

In the SudsLibrary documentation there is an example for the keyword [Switch Soap client](http://ombre42.github.io/robotframework-sudslibrary/doc/SudsLibrary.html#Switch%20Soap%20Client). This supports your approach, so I'm guessing that the problem might be different.