# How to consult a second Web Service with the first web service login robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

I have two Web Services with the request.

Web service to login :

```
username password parameters
```

Second Web service also :

```
username password parameters second ws
```

I need to access second web service with the credentials of the first. How can I do this?

Comment: You access the second exactly the same way you access the first. Can you be a bit more explicit about what you need help with? Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043647/how-access-to-2-web-services-with-1-session-robot-framework

Comment: No because, when i access to second, the frist session end

Comment: Can you be more clear what "No" means? "No, not a duplciate", or "No, I can't show what I tried"? Why should we not close this as a duplicate of your other question?

Comment: I think is not a duplciate ;)

Comment: WHY is it not a duplicate? What's different about this question? Should we close the other question?

Comment: At SO we provide support for technical programming problems. This requires questions to provide a [mcve]. This includes code examples and explanation of what has already been tried but deemed unsuccesful. At least it prevents others from trying what you've already tried and provides insight on the issue at hand. Please consult the SO help sections on how to ask questions when this is not clear.